# this to that via function?

Tags: jquery

I have the following script:

```
$('#element_1').live('click', function() {
    function_1(this)
});

function function_1(that) {
    that = that.attr("id").split('_');

    alert(that[0]);
    alert(that[1]);
}
```

I am trying to split the id attribute of "this", but I get an error:

Object does not support this property or method.

However, when I do the same thing directly in the click event e.g.

```
$('#element_1').live('click', function() {
    var that = $(this).attr("id").split('_');

    alert(that[0]);
    alert(that[1]);
});
```

How do I get the top version of the script to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap `this` with jQuery first:

```
function_1($(this));
```

(Note that you do this correctly in the second version, which is why it works).

---

What's even better is to access the `id` **without** jQuery:

```
that = that.id.split('_');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#element_1').live('click', function() {
    function_1(this)
});

    function function_1(that) {
    that = $(that).attr("id").split('_');

    alert(that[0]);
    alert(that[1]);
}
```

just add the $ for `that`, or change the line `function_1(this)` to `function_1($(this))`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to wrap `this` in jQuery in the first example.

Rewrite

```
$('#element_1').live('click', function() {
    function_1(this)
});
```

to

```
$('#element_1').live('click', function() {
    function_1($(this));
});
```

and it should work.

A regular HTML element object does not have an `attr` method (it’s specific to jQuery); hence the error.

Answer (score 0):

Call function_1 like this
function_1($(this));